# Customise the content pane of a Swift UI context menu

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm newish to SwiftUI.

I have two questions about customising the content pane you see when you activate a [context menu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contextmenu(_:)) in Swift UI.

It's seeming to me, after research across the web and Apple documentation, that the content pane of the context menu in Swift UI can only be a scaled representation of the View you've added that modifier to.

However, it seems like it must be possible to customise it, as there are examples in iOS of context menus with more extensibility than I've seen the SwiftUI api expose (such as the news items below, which seem to load in content).

Is it actually possible at all to customise the content pane of a context menu with the Swift UI API that Apple has provided to date?

**Some examples:**

News context menus seem to load page content directly
[image]

Safari has a show/hide preview feature.

[image]